# Why the MAX_GROUP_SIZE is 7 in CP Subsystem?

Tags: hazelcast

public static final int MAX_GROUP_SIZE = 7;
A CP group consists of an odd number of CPMembers between 3 and 7.

why is it 7? not more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CP subsystem is in implementation of the RAFT consensus algorithm that guarantees consistency even in the event of node failures.   In order to correctly implement RAFT, parts of the CP subsystem are implemented with synchronous behavior (where similar features in an AP subsystem could be implemented asynchronously).

This synchronous implementation means that the more nodes that participate in the subsystem, the more there is a potential for delay due to a slow-responding member.   There is also additional network traffic required to support each additional node since all nodes participate in each update.

As a result, limiting the size of the cluster helps maintain high performance and low latency.   If more nodes are needed, the CP subsystem allows the configuration of multiple consistency groups, each of which can have between 3 and 7 nodes.  In this way, the overall size of the CP subsystem is unlimited; as long as it is partitioned up into consistency groups of manageable size.